# vue3, composition api, ref array, replacement is not forcing rererendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

In my app I want to occasionally replace my ref<number[]> array with a new array, which is **not** a ref. The way I did it, was

```
  list2.value = listNoRef;
  console.log(list2.value);
```

The array `list2` is used inisde my template to render a list.
My logging is schowing, that the `Proxy` has a modified `Target` with the right values, **but** my browser is not rerendering. If there is another event happening, which forces a rerender, the list is shown with the added values.

### Example

info:

- `addAnswer1()` -> works
- `addAnswer2()` -> ❗problem❗
- `addAnswer2Clear()` -> works

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const list1 = ref<number[]>([]);
const list2 = ref<number[]>([]);
let idx1 = 0;
let idx2 = 0;

const listNoRef: number[] = []

function addAnswer1() {
  list1.value.push(idx1);
  console.log(list1.value);
  idx1++;
}

function addAnswer2() {
  listNoRef.push(idx2);
  list2.value = listNoRef;
  console.log(list2.value);
  idx2++;
}

function addAnswer2Clear() {
  listNoRef.push(idx2);
  list2.value = [];
  list2.value = listNoRef;
  console.log(list2.value);
  idx2++;
}

</script>

<template>
  <h1>My Test</h1>
  <h2>addAnswer1</h2>
  <button @click="addAnswer1()">addAnswer1</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list1" :key="item">idx:{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>{{ list1.length }}</div>
  <h2>addAnswer2</h2>
  <button @click="addAnswer2()">addAnswer2</button>
  <button @click="addAnswer2Clear()">addAnswer2Clear</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list2" :key="item">idx:{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>{{ list2.length }}</div>
</template>
```

*note: This is a stripped down example. I used a similar implementation to reset a list inside a callback, after an async api call finished.*

### Additions

I looked for `vue ref array replace rerender ...` related problems, but haven't found my specific case.

My current workaround is to clear the list of the `.value` and reassign it afterwards

```js
 function addAnswer2Clear() {
  listNoRef.push(idx2);
  list2.value = [];
  list2.value = listNoRef;
  console.log(list2.value);
  idx2++;
}
```

What is the reason behind this problem and is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `list2.value = [...listNoRef]` (copy by value not by reference) :

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const list1 = ref([]);
    const list2 = ref([]);
    let idx1 = 0;
    let idx2 = 0;

    const listNoRef = []

    function addAnswer1() {
      list1.value.push(idx1);
      console.log(list1.value);
      idx1++;
    }

    function addAnswer2() {
      listNoRef.push(idx2);
      list2.value = [...listNoRef];
      console.log(list2.value);
      idx2++;
    }

    return {
      list1, list2, addAnswer1, addAnswer2
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h1>My Test</h1>
  <h2>addAnswer1</h2>
  <button @click="addAnswer1()">addAnswer1</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list1" :key="item">idx:{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>{{ list1.length }}</div>
  <h2>addAnswer2</h2>
  <button @click="addAnswer2()">addAnswer2</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list2" :key="item">idx:{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  <div>{{ list2.length }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The spread operator is an okay solution, but more importantly for me, you solved my missing understanding, why no rerendering was triggered: If I assign an array reference with changed elements inside, there is no change detected by vue. The `refernce` stayed the same, but the content changed. Have a nice day